# php need to sort arrays in array and get respective key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort the following multidimensional array in php and thereafter get the respective key of any array that I want:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    4 => "404"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    5 => "373"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    6 => "305"
  ]
]
```

In the above case, I would like to get the position / key of 5 after sorting 404, 373 and 305.

The result of this should be value `2`.

Comment: you want the last index number in response?

Comment: please add the result you want...

Comment: not the last index. the index of 5 after sorting

Comment: the result should be value 2

Comment: Have you looked into [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and tried it yourself? There is a comparison of sorting functions.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of the array you want to have, as well as what you already tried. It's hard to help you if we don't know precisely what you want and why it didn't work.

Comment: Been doing this for half an hour but no breakthrough yet. This is not a duplicate as its a multidimensional array

Comment: If your sub arrays always contain 1 element it should be faily easy to use `usort` so sort the base array and after that get your index.

Comment: Then just do a `foreach`-loop. That's easy enough.

Comment: You keep answering to the comments, but didn't edit your question to provide the output you are looking for. Your question is likely to have already been flaged and might be closed soon. You should hurry.

Comment: @ksjohn I think that  _"I would like to get the position / key of 5"_ together with _"The result of this should be value 2"_ in the OP's question actually _does_ answer that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yup. Which gives me the impression that the OP didn't actually tried to solve the issue. This can be solved with a foreach, with a `array_merge()` and can be unsolved by a variety of less correct solutions that the OP might have tried from lack of experience or feature bias. I'm under the impression that either the OP gave a flawed description of the issue or simply didn't try. Providing his tryings would have answered that.

Comment: I'm the kind of guy who keeps and a [php][arrays] SO tab around and give away some working code without much questions, since I know how many PHP developers are (self-taught) beginner programmers and how data structures can be tricky for these. Still, there are questions like this, where I see no effort although the issue is fairly simple and therefore doubt any learning will come out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a foreach-loop:

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    4 => "404"
  ],
  1 => [
    5 => "373"
  ],
  2 => [
    6 => "305"
  ]
];

foreach ($array as $index => $arr) {
    if (array_key_exists(5, $arr)) {
        echo $index + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/HH54K

Even though PHP has a bunch of built in array-functions, they can't do everything, and they are sometimes much slower than a simple `foreach`.